# Transition: JQuery Mobile Not Recognizing Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a JQuery Mobile WebApp, using JQuery Mobile 1.4.2. When a new page loads, a visual error happens briefly during the page transition:

[image: themeTransition]

I believe this is a problem with the theme not being applied during the transition, and when the next page is fully loaded, the theme shows correctly again.

The following is an attribute of both pages: `data-theme="a"`

Page Declaration:

```
<section id="landmarks" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
```

Back Button Declaration:

```
<a href="#landmarks" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">Back</a>
```

JSFiddle (click on the "page 2" button, and please notice the change of the nav bar color during the transition): http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/stNpV/

Is there a function that should be called before rendering the page to correctly render the back button and the header-bar text?

Comment: Please provide a working sample fiddle...

Comment: I added a sample JS Fiddle. Please notice the change of the nav bar's color during the transition. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The data-id="appHeader" in your header is causing the issue. Remove that attribute and your fiddle works fine:

> **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/stNpV/1/)**

```
<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
</header>
```

If you need the data attribute, rename it to something other than id, e.g.

```
data-appid="appHeader"
```

If you look at the jQM reference (http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/), you will see that the framework uses data-id.

Comment: data-id is here with a reason, it used to be used to prevent header/footer transitioning during content transition. It still works but badly. OK this is under assumption that he really need this functionality :)

Comment: @Gajotres, thanks for the clarification! I was not sure why that was there.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is using the old pre jQuery Mobile way of achieving permanent footer/header.

jQuery Mobile uses completely different approach.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/stNpV/3/

#### HTML:

```
<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="appHeader" id="appHeader">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
</header>

<section data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page1">    
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">Page 2</a>
    </div>
</section>

<section data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page2">    
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#page1" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Page 21</a>
    </div>    
</section>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#appHeader').enhanceWithin().toolbar();
});

$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function () {
    activePage = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage');
    pageId = activePage.prop('id'); 

    if (pageId === 'page1') {
        activePage.parent().find('.ui-header h1').html('Page 1');
    }

    if (pageId === 'page2') {
        activePage.parent().find('.ui-header h1').html('Page 2');
    }    
});
```